# EditorJs warning "«blocks.stretchBlock()» is deprecated and will be removed in the next major release. Please use the «BlockAPI» instead."

Tags: javascript, editorjs

I'm using EditorJs but it is giving me this warning in the console

`«blocks.stretchBlock()» is deprecated and will be removed in the next major release. Please use the «BlockAPI» instead.`

How can I use `«BlockAPI»` in EditorJs?

Here is my EditorJs init:

```js
const editor = new EditorJS({
  tools: {
    header: Header,
    list: List,
    image: Image,
    embed: {
      class: Embed,
      config: {
        services: {
          youtube: true
        }
      }
    },
  },
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Block API is passed via constructor props in `block` prop. You have to get it from there and set it to your block's property.

It should look something like this:

```js
class CustomBlock {
  private data;
  private block;

  constructor({
    data,
    block
  }) {
    this.data = data;
    this.block = block;
  }

  toggleStretched() {
    this.block.stretched = !!this.data.stretched;
  }

  // Rest of the block implementation
}
```

It seems that the official docs aren't up-to-date, however I found [this file](https://github.com/codex-team/editor.js/blob/9c0fc48d89afe725d6e27532884d15a78ea32081/docs/api.md#block-api) with a description of Block API.